# Get other or all classes of an item

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

Given the HTML:

```
<div id="carrousel-wrapper">
  <div class="region region-carousel-1">
    ....
  </div>
  <div class="region region-carousel-2">
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

I walk trough the selectors as follows:

```
  var wrapper = $('#carousel-wrapper .region');
  if(wrapper.length) {
    $(wrapper).each(function(i) {
      var regionClass = 'region-carousel-' + (i + 1);
```

But I want a cleaner way to find regionClass. The current way breaks in cases where e.g. `.region-carousel-1` does not exist.

How can I retrieve the "additional" subclasses for `.carrousel-wrapper .region`?

Comment: Maybe there is a better solution (other than Rory's) if you take a step back and explain the bigger picture. Why you need to find the class? What are you doing with it?

Comment: I am certain that there is a better solution, but unfortunately doing so, requires quite some rewriting (and even migrating) of existing contnent and functionality. I have a refactoring planned, which includes a.o. a much simpler solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `each()` method you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the current element. Also, the `if (wrapper.length)` check is redundant as the `each()` method won't throw an error if there are no elements provided to it. Finally, you're double-wrapping the `wrapper` variable in a jQuery object.

With all that in mind, the below should work for you:

```
var wrapper = $('#carousel-wrapper .region');
wrapper.each(function(i) {
    var regionClass = $(this).attr("class");
});
```

Comment: In your example, regionClass is the string `.region region-carousel-1`. But I want the part `region-carousel-1`. Obviously, I can preg-match extract that, but is there no cleaner way?

Comment: Unfortunately not, although a regular expression to get `region-carousel-x` should be pretty straight-forward.